# One word phrase search to avoid stemming in Solr

Tags: search, lucene, solr, stemming

I have stemming enabled in my Solr instance, I had assumed that in order to perform an exact word search without disabling stemming, it would be as simple as putting the word into quotes. This however does not appear to be the case?

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simple way, if what you're referring to is the "slop" (required similarity) as part of a fuzzy search (see the [Lucene Query Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html) here).

For example, if I perform this search:

```
 q=field_name:determine
```

I see results that contain "determine", "determining", "determined", etc.. If I then modify the query like so:

```
 q=field_name:determine~1
```

I only see results that contain the word "determine". This is because I'm specifying a required similarity of 1, which means "exact match". I can specify this value anywhere from 0 to 1.

Comment: Looks like the definition has changed with some Solr version: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/the-standard-query-parser.html#fuzzy-searches. Now `~0` seems to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do is index the same text without stemming in one field, and with stemming in another. Boost the non-stemmed field & that should prefer exact versions of words to stemmed versions. Of course you could also write your own query parser that directs quoted phrases to the non-stemmed field only.