# Exact word search in Solr

Tags: search, lucene, solr, stemming

I have a question which closely relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215389/solr-one-word-phrase-search-to-avoid-stemming).

In my schema I have a field

```
<field name="text" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

This gives an exact match, ie. stemming disabled

> eat = eat

Is it possible, while configured to textgen to search for other variants of the word

> eg. eat = eat, eats, eating

eat~0 will give similar sounding words such as meat, beat etc. but this is not what I want.

I'm starting to think that the only way to achieve this is to add another field with something other then textgen but if there is a simpler way I am very interested to hear it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `copyfield` statements is the normal approach in Solr. Since `stemming` is the answer to exactly what you're asking, this is what I recommend you to use. You can set `stored=false` if you are worried about index size.

You might also use `lemmatisation`, which is the opposite of stemming - where you instead add a words all inflected forms. This is typically performed on the search query, expanding e.g., `eat` to `eat, eats, eating` etc.

The third alternative might be to use wildcard search, although I wouldn't encourage it. Not least since it bypasses all schema configured filters for the target field.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `text` as the field type, then eat, eats, eaten and eating will all be stored as `eat` and a search for `FieldName:eat` will find all of them. If you change the field type to `text-gen` then the search for `FieldName:eat` will only find "eat", not eats, eaten or eating.